# How to display the Environment variables of a Slave node in Jenkins on Slack?

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins, hudson, slack

I have turned on Slack notifications in the Configure part of the project(which is linked to the master node) in Jenkins. After a build gets completed in Jenkins, I observe 2 nodes, the master node and the slave node on which the build occurs. The Environment Variables corresponding to the master node get displayed on Slack after the build gets completed. The Environment variables of the slave node,which include the user-defined Environment variables, which get injected during the build process, however, don't get displayed on Slack. However, the Environment variables of the slave node, can be seen on the console output. These Environment variables however don't get updated in the Master node and hence don't get displayed on Slack. Any solutions to this problem please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I have figured out a way to solve this issue.
The steps which I had followed were as follows:

1. Go to Configure->Post-Build Actions->Slack Notifications
2. Then go to Trigger for matrix projects and select the drop down list,
   [as shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vEc58.png)

3. Here, we see 3 options in the dropdown menu:

a) Trigger for parent job: This would display the Environment variables of only the master node on Slack

b) Trigger for each configuration: This would display the Environment variables of only the slave node on Slack

c) Trigger for parent and each configuration: This would display the Environment variables of both the master node and slave node(in 2 separate messages) on Slack.

Pre-requisites for this approach: Slack plugin should be installed on Jenkins